# JSON Web Request string to parsed data with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am using .net to call to a webservice then parse it to usable data.
Right now I am experimenting with this call: http://www.reddit.com/r/all.json
Which returns: http://pastebin.com/AbV4yVuC
This is put in to a string, which I called jsontxt.

I am using JSON.NET to parse the information but it doesn't seem to be working.  I initially tried to deserialize it as an object and it didn't work as nothing is put in to the variable

Then I tried to deserialize it as a dataset and I'm having no luck again.  My error was

> > An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

MY CODE:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace tutorialresult1
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var jsontxt = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.reddit.com/r/all.json");
           // Console.Write(json);

            // -----Deserializing by Object--------------
            //MediaEmbed account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MediaEmbed>(jsontxt);
            //Console.WriteLine(account.width);   //COMES OUT TO NULL

            // -----Deserializing by DataSet--------------
            DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsontxt);
            DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["Children"];
            Console.WriteLine(dataTable.Rows.Count);
        }

    }

    public class MediaEmbed
    {
        public string content { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public bool scrolling { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }
.... //rest of classes here for each json which were generated with http://json2csharp.com/
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to make the JSON easily accessible by parsing it.

Comment: In order to deserialize to a `DataSet`, the JSON data must be in a very specific format.  Reddit data is not in that format.  So, you either need to use strongly typed classes, as shown in Craig W's answer, or deserialize to a `JObject` or a `dynamic` variable.  Here is [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20896057/10263) that explains all of this in a little more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [json2charp](http://json2csharp.com/) I generated the following set of classes. Using those you should be able to deserialize the JSON into RootObject using JSON.NET.

```
var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsontxt);
```

.

```
public class MediaEmbed
{
    public string content { get; set; }
    public int? width { get; set; }
    public bool? scrolling { get; set; }
    public int? height { get; set; }
}

public class Oembed
{
    public string provider_url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string author_name { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
    public int thumbnail_width { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string provider_name { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
    public int thumbnail_height { get; set; }
    public string author_url { get; set; }
}

public class SecureMedia
{
    public Oembed oembed { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class SecureMediaEmbed
{
    public string content { get; set; }
    public int? width { get; set; }
    public bool? scrolling { get; set; }
    public int? height { get; set; }
}

public class Oembed2
{
    public string provider_url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int thumbnail_width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string provider_name { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int thumbnail_height { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string author_name { get; set; }
    public string author_url { get; set; }
}

public class Media
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Oembed2 oembed { get; set; }
}

public class Data2
{
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public object banned_by { get; set; }
    public MediaEmbed media_embed { get; set; }
    public string subreddit { get; set; }
    public string selftext_html { get; set; }
    public string selftext { get; set; }
    public object likes { get; set; }
    public SecureMedia secure_media { get; set; }
    public string link_flair_text { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int gilded { get; set; }
    public SecureMediaEmbed secure_media_embed { get; set; }
    public bool clicked { get; set; }
    public bool stickied { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public Media media { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public object approved_by { get; set; }
    public bool over_18 { get; set; }
    public bool hidden { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string subreddit_id { get; set; }
    public object edited { get; set; }
    public string link_flair_css_class { get; set; }
    public object author_flair_css_class { get; set; }
    public int downs { get; set; }
    public bool saved { get; set; }
    public bool is_self { get; set; }
    public string permalink { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double created { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public object author_flair_text { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public double created_utc { get; set; }
    public int ups { get; set; }
    public int num_comments { get; set; }
    public bool visited { get; set; }
    public object num_reports { get; set; }
    public object distinguished { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public Data2 data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string modhash { get; set; }
    public List<Child> children { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
    public object before { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to highlight that he needs to deserialize to the `type RootObject`. ie. `RootObject account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsontxt);`

Comment: I assumed the OP understood that as the code he posted showed he had a basic understanding of specifying the type to deserialize into.

Comment: Yes, but he also had access to the types you have displayed from json2csharp (judging by the comments next to his MediaEmbed class and failed to make the connection. :)

Comment: If I was to deserialize it, how would I access the data?  Using a .  won't work, like in account.title   (That's just an example)

Comment: The same way you access any property of any object, with dot notation. `account.data.after` would get you the `after` property of the `Data` instance. If it's a collection (like `children` in `Data`) you would loop over it or you LINQ.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was able to access the data.  I didn't know I had access it like in jquery/javascript.

Comment: @user3704986 don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you to resolve the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to deserialize a json-string into a dataset-object. But the json-string doesn't have the format of a dataset. So you need to create a class which matches the json or deserialize it into a dictionary or sth. like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deserialize using the following? Seems to be more robust for me.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
...
var x = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Obj_type>(jsonstring);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

as purplej0kr mentioned you will need to have a .Net model to use for `Obj_type` (and it will need to match the object you are parsing) or this will not work.

You will need the `System.Web.Extensions.dll` referenced in your project (right click add reference, dll is usually under 'Assemblies'). Otherwise:
[Where can I find the assembly System.Web.Extensions dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520569/where-can-i-find-the-assembly-system-web-extensions-dll)

Comment: It says it cannot find a reference for 'using System.Web.Script.Serialization;'